# How to find Prometheus latest version with curl?

Tags: prometheus

I'd need to collect Prometheus's latest version using a cURL http request. So far, I can see that Prometheus releases are published under https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/ . However, that would need to parse somehow the whole HTML page to find it.
Is there a more direct way to capture the latest version of Prometheus?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/latest
```

`/latest` will redirect you to the version tagged as latest